# Exception number and string

Tags: android, exception

Is there a way of getting an exception number to control better what had happened?

For example:

```
    try
    { Do some work
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {  if(e.**ExceptionNumber** == Value)
          Toast("Show message");
       else
          Toast("Error doing some work: " + e.toString());        
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch different exceptions if you want to handle them differently.

```
try{

}catch(IOException e1){
  //-- if io error--
}catch(FormatException e2){
  //--if format error--
}catch(Exception e3){
  //--any thing else --
}
```

Most Java API Exceptions **do not have** special integers, they have a type, a message and a cause.

But, You can create your own type of exceptions too:

```
public class MyIntegerException extends Exception{
  private int num;

  public int getInteger(){
    return num;
  }

  public MyIntegerException(int n, String msg){
    super(msg);
    this.num = n;
  }
}
```

throw :

```
throw new MyIntegerException(1024,"This is a 1024 error");
```

catch:

```
catch(MyIntegerException e){
  int num = e.getInteger();
  //--do something with integer--
}
```

Comment: I just need "catch(Exception e3)". I want to log in a database of erros. I need an integer of the exception not a string.

Comment: @Ton Java's exception do not store special numbers for error. updated  in answer.

Comment: ok. thanks. I guess there is no solution. If there are not error codes as integers I guess I have to compare Strings.

Answer (score 0):

if you know what can go wrong, you can throw your own exception and add your custom text into it:

```
try{
  //code to execute
  //in case of an error
  throw new Exception("Your message here");
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can also define your own exceptions type, like the person above said and you can throw display a different message depending on the exception type that occurred.